# how to identify nodejs framework

Tags: node.js

I am new to nodejs, I have been working on php and yii since long time,
now i have got one project which is written in node js, It's already developed by another developer, I need to figure out which node framework they have used to build this project, So i can start learning things towards that framework,
Someone please help me to figure out that, I need kick of this project real soon.

```
Folder Struhcture:
../bin
../config
../controllers
../events
../explorer
../helpers
../initializers
../middleware
../models
../node_modules
../routes
../schema
../var
../views
```

Dependencies:

```
    "when": "",
    "colors": "",
    "config": "",
    "restify": "",
    "node-uuid": "~1.4.0",
    "node-recurly": "",
    "node-recurlyjs-sign": "",
    "promise-object": "",
    "requester": "",
    "qs": "",
    "validator": "",
    "underscore": "",
    "bcrypt": "",
    "mysql": "",
    "bit-array": "",
    "node-hipchat": "",
    "mime": "~1.2.11",
    "filed": "~0.1.0",
    "async": "~0.2.9",
    "nodemailer": "0.3.x",
    "email-templates": "0.0.5",
    "handlebars": "~1.0.12",
    "time": "~0.9.2",
    "cluster": "~0.7.7",
    "ent": "~0.1.0",
    "log4js": ""
```

Comment: go to `package.json` and see the `dependencies`.

Comment: @Mritunjay: i have just added dependencies in a question

Comment: It may use restify to build the web services. You should check the startup code in this project .

Answer (score 2):

Based purely on the dependencies listed, it looks like your app is using `Restify` as the services framework (for http services), `handlebars` for the templating framework, and `underscore` for the utility helpers.

Comment: Although handlebars seem to be there for emailing purposes. Restify is usually an API only server, no front-end.

Comment: Then again, there is a views folder

Comment: Yes, Restify would be there to provide API endpoints for HTTP requests in the same way that another framework like Express would.

Comment: I know, I'm just saying that it isn't usually used that way. At least in my experience. When people want a full webapp stack, they go with express&co. When they aim only for an API, they use Restify. Though there are exceptions.